# ActiveMQ high priority messages consumed slowly

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a queue with a huge amount of messages with normal priority, when I push high priority message into the queue it takes around 2 minutes to dispatch which is too slow.

I've noticed that when I click refresh inside the queue over ActiveMQ console then sort the priority descending, the high priority messages consumed very quickly.

I have 2 consumers for this queue with below configurations:
apache-activemq-5.15.11
`prioritizedMessages="true" useCache="false"`
`constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1"`
`jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1`

Comment: Are you suggesting that sorting the messages in the web console has a direct impact on how quickly they are delivered to consumers?

Comment: That's what I noticed, After refresh and sort the high priority messages consumed very quickly, but if I keep it as is it took around 2 minutes.